# setcookie() is returning false. sessions wont work either

Tags: php, session, cookies

My code consists of a setcookie before any other code.
I made it so that if setcookie returns false, the code will tell me.

Every time I run it, it returns false. What's wrong?

`$l = setcookie('token', $token);
    if (!$l) {
        die("Cookie could not set");
    }`

> Output: Cookie could not set

I have used sessions also, and every time I try the cookie for session id never sets.

Is my browser broken or am I broken?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

As the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) says:

> If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail and return FALSE.

This means that somewhere before you call `setcookie`, you are generating some output (perhaps from an echo, or some raw HTML). You need to put the call to `setcookie` before any other output is generated from your PHP file.

Comment: Nick is correct unfortunately.  You've got a potential needle in a haystack quest ahead of you I fear.

Comment: Right.  I saw this, and eventually I just literally rewrote letter by letter the code into a new document and it worked. Thanks for putting me on the trail!